# How to sign with a grapical image signature using cosign SOAP API

Tags: cosign-api

I am trying to sign a pdf file using CoSign Web servies API. I have tried the code sample and I was able to sign successfully. I am using the developer account and I have created several graphical signatures, but the resulting signature did not contain any images (only textual information) although I had set the appearanceMask to graphical image.

here is the sample code I am using:

```
package trial;

import com.arx.sapiws.dss._1.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import oasis.names.tc.dss._1_0.core.schema.*;
import oasis.names.tc.saml._1_0.assertion.NameIdentifierType;

public class CosignHelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

        String fileName = "D:/demo - Copy.pdf";
        String signerUsername = "";
        String signerPassword = "";

        System.out.println("Trying to sign '" + fileName + "' by '" + signerUsername + "' with password '" + signerPassword + "' ...");
        if (!checkFile(fileName)) {
            System.out.println("Cannot find '" + fileName + "' or it is read/write protected. Aborting.");
            return;
        }

        //set document properties
        DocumentType.Base64Data corePDFBytes = new DocumentType.Base64Data();
        byte[] fileBytes = getPDFBytes(fileName);
        corePDFBytes.setValue(fileBytes);
        corePDFBytes.setMimeType("application/pdf");
        DocumentType myDoc = new DocumentType();
        myDoc.setBase64Data(corePDFBytes);

        // set signer - USERNAME/DOMAIN
        NameIdentifierType cosignUserProps = new NameIdentifierType();
        cosignUserProps.setValue(signerUsername);
        cosignUserProps.setNameQualifier(" ");

        // set signer - PASSWORD
        CoSignAuthDataType cosignPassword = new CoSignAuthDataType();
        cosignPassword.setLogonPassword(signerPassword);

        // set signer - USERNAME+PASSWORD
        ClaimedIdentity cosignUser = new ClaimedIdentity();
        cosignUser.setName(cosignUserProps);
        cosignUser.setSupportingInfo(cosignPassword);

        //set signature field settings
        SAPISigFieldSettingsType sigFieldSettings = new SAPISigFieldSettingsType();
        sigFieldSettings.setName("SigField");
        sigFieldSettings.setInvisible(Boolean.FALSE);   //visible
        sigFieldSettings.setX(150);
        sigFieldSettings.setY(110);
        sigFieldSettings.setWidth(150);
        sigFieldSettings.setHeight(50);
        sigFieldSettings.setDependencyMode(DependencyModeEnum.INDEPENDENT);
        sigFieldSettings.setSignatureType(SignatureTypeEnum.DIGITAL);
        sigFieldSettings.setAppearanceMask(11L);
        sigFieldSettings.setEmptyFieldLabel("");
        sigFieldSettings.setPage(1);

        //initiate request components
        RequestBaseType.InputDocuments inputs = new RequestBaseType.InputDocuments();
        inputs.getOtherOrDocumentHashOrTransformedData().add(myDoc);

        RequestBaseType.OptionalInputs optInputs = new RequestBaseType.OptionalInputs();
        optInputs.setSignatureType("http://arx.com/SAPIWS/DSS/1.0/signature-field-create-sign");
        optInputs.setClaimedIdentity(cosignUser);
        optInputs.setSAPISigFieldSettings(sigFieldSettings);
        optInputs.setReturnPDFTailOnly(Boolean.TRUE);

        //initiate connection to COSign SAPI service
        DSS service = new DSS(new URL("https://prime.cosigntrial.com:8080/sapiws/dss.asmx"));
        DSSSoap port = service.getDSSSoap12();

        //initiate request
        SignRequest request = new SignRequest();
        request.setOptionalInputs(optInputs);
        request.setInputDocuments(inputs);
        request.setRequestID("DummyRequestId");

        //make the call
        DssSignResult result = port.dssSign(request);

        //CHECK RESULT:
        ResponseBaseType.Result rc = result.getResult();
        String errmsg = rc.getResultMajor();
        if (errmsg.compareTo("urn:oasis:names:tc:dss:1.0:resultmajor:Success") != 0) {
            System.out.println("Cannot sign '" + fileName + "' got: " + rc.getResultMessage().getValue());
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Trying to append signature to '" + fileName + "' ('" + signerUsername + "') ...");

        // IF OK Get the signature:
        DssSignResult.SignatureObject sigObj = result.getSignatureObject();
        DssSignResult.SignatureObject.Base64Signature sigBase64 = sigObj.getBase64Signature();

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName, true);
            fos.write(sigBase64.getValue());
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error writing to PDF file: " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Signature of '" + signerUsername + "' appended to '" + fileName + "'.");
    }

    private static byte[] getPDFBytes(String FileName) {
        byte[] pdf;
        // READ THE FILE INTO BUFFER
        try {
            File file = new File(FileName);

            if (!file.canRead()) {
                return null;
            }

            if (!file.canWrite()) {
                return null;
            }

            pdf = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            FileInputStream fos = new FileInputStream(file);
            fos.read(pdf, 0, (int) file.length());
            fos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
        return pdf;
    }

    private static boolean checkFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            File file = new File(fileName);

            if (!file.canRead()) {
                return false;
            }

            if (!file.canWrite()) {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have more than a single graphical signature in your CoSign account, you must indicate the default one to use for signing in your SAPI code.

A simple way to do it is by providing the name of the default graphical signature as part of the configuration values. Add the following code snippet to your code:

```
ArrayOfConfValueType confValArray = new ArrayOfConfValueType();
ConfValueType confVal = new ConfValueType();
confVal.setConfValueID(ConfIDEnum.GR_SIG_PREF_NAME);
confVal.setStringValue("{GRAPHICAL_IMAGE_NAME}");
confValArray.getConfValue().add(confVal);
optInputs.setConfigurationValues(confValArray);
```